# String.split() not working properly, Scanner not reading properly, something is wrong

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm having no idea why the split command is not working for me, and the sc.nextLine(); command is also not reading properly my input, the program is outputting these:

```
Menu:
1 - Sign up on service.
```

This is my input from the keyboard

```
1
```

Program output:

```
Input a single line separated by COMMA and NO SPACES, the software will validade your entry.
1 - Your First Name, 2 - Your Second Name, 3 - Your Age, 4 - Your Gender 
(F or M in UPPER CASE) 5 - Your Email, 6 - Your Password:
```

My second input:

```
Vanessa,Jhonson,25, M,aaa@aol.com,111222
```

Now the output after my input. This is the output from the for loop to print the String array k[], not close from what is should be, no idea why.

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302 
Wrong input pattern, try again. //this is the output if the string s doesn't match the regex


Menu: //Program looping (expected)
1 - Sign up on service.
```

This code below is my source code, it has this main Method and another Method from another class wich you will fine right after this one.

```
package view;

import java.util.Scanner;
import control.RegistrationController;

public class ClientFacade {
    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean exit = false;
        int option = 0;
        RegistrationController rc = new RegistrationController();

        while(exit == false){
            System.out.println("Menu:");
            System.out.println("1 - Sign up on service.");

            option = sc.nextInt(); //ERROR AT THIS LINE

            switch(option){

            case 0:{
                exit = true;
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                rc.userSignUp();
                break;
            }
            default:{
                System.out.println("Invalid option.");
                break;
            }
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

The code below is a Method from this program.
package control;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import view.ClientFacade;
import model.Person;
import model.Server;

public class RegistrationController {

public void userSignUp(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    User usr = new User();
    RegistrationController rc = new RegistrationController();
    String regex = "$(\\w)+(\\,)(\\w)+(\\,)(\\d){2,3}(\\,)[F,M](\\,)(\\w)+(@)(\\w)+(.)(\\w)+((.)(\\w)+)?(,)(\\w)+^";
    System.out.println("Input a single line separated by COMMA and NO SPACES, "
            + "the software will validade your entry.\n"
            + "1 - Your First Name, 2 - Your Second Name, "
            + "3 - Your Age, 4 - Your Gender \n(F or M in UPPER CASE) "
            + "5 - Your Email, 6 - Your Password:\n");

    String s = sc.nextLine();               //BUG, NOT ABLE TO READ A PROPER STRING
    s = s.trim();
    String [] k = s.split("(\\,)");         //THIS IS ABSOLUTELY NOT WORKING FOR NO REASON

    System.out.println(s);                  //DEBUGGING LINE
    for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {    //DEBUGGING BLOCK
        String string = k[i];
        System.out.println(k);
    }


    if (Pattern.matches(regex, s)){
        usr.setAdmLevel(0);
        usr.setName(k[0]+" "+k[1]);
        usr.setAge(Integer.parseInt(k[2]));
        usr.setGender(k[3]);
        usr.setEmail(k[4]);
        usr.setPassword(k[5]);
        if (rc.registerUser(usr) != 0){
            System.out.println("Your are signed up! Your ID: "+usr.getId());
        }else {
            System.out.println("A problem ocurred, not registered.");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Wrong input pattern, try again.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No need `\\\` in `s.split("(\\,)");`

Comment: `System.out.println(k);` should be `System.out.println(k[i])`. You're calling `toString()` on an array - that's never a good idea...

Comment: and your regex pattern is also not correct as per your input

Comment: You've also got a space in your input ", M" which doesn't follow your own instructions.

Comment: this line: s = s.trim(); should eliminate the spaces @user2696372, but is isn't happening

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, the regular expression regex initiator and terminator was inverted, it was `"$^"` when it should be `"^$"` , I also found out that `s.trimm();` doesn't work for a full string with commas, so I did trimm them after that string was split, inside a for-each block.

```
for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {    //TRIMMING BLOCK
            k[i] = k[i].trim();
            System.out.println(k[i]);
        }
```